# How to recreate the Photos grid transition animation from Months to Years in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, matchedgeometryeffect

In the stock Photos app, there's a transition animation when switching the view from Month to Year. Initially each month is represented as a single cell but when switching to year, the cells combine into a single new cell. A similar animation style can be seen [here](https://new.computer/assets/section_7_1.mp4) as well.

I'm attempting my hand at recreating using a combination of LazyVGrid and matchedGeometryEffect but the cells don't combine smoothly like in the video. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestV: View {
    @Namespace private var namespace
    @State private var isExpanded = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                if !isExpanded {
                    SubviewOne(namespace: namespace, isExpanded: $isExpanded)
                        .transition(.offset())
                } else {
                    SubviewTwo(namespace: namespace, isExpanded: $isExpanded)
                        .transition(.offset())
                }

            }
            Spacer()
            Toggle(isOn: $isExpanded.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2)), label: { Text("Matched") }).frame(width: 140)
        }
    }
}

struct SubviewOne: View {
    
    var namespace: Namespace.ID
    @Binding var isExpanded: Bool
    let colors: [Color] = [.red, .orange, .yellow, .green, .blue, .purple]
    let groups = ["one", "two", "two"]
    var gridItemLayout = [GridItem(.flexible())]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: gridItemLayout, spacing: 0) {
                ForEach((0...2), id: \.self) { num in
                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle().fill(colors[num % colors.count])
                        Text("\(num)")
                            .font(.system(size: 30))
                    }
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: isExpanded ? groups[num]:"", in: namespace, isSource: false)
                        .frame(height: 150)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SubviewTwo: View {
    var namespace: Namespace.ID
    @Binding var isExpanded: Bool
    let colors: [Color] = [.red, .orange, .yellow, .green, .blue, .purple]
    let groups = ["one", "two"]
    var gridItemLayout = [GridItem(.flexible())]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: gridItemLayout, spacing: 20) {
                ForEach((0...1), id: \.self) { num in
                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle().fill(colors[num % colors.count])
                        Text("\(num)")
                            .font(.system(size: 30))
                    }
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id:groups[num], in: namespace)
                    .frame(width: 350, height: 250)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    TestV()
}
```

Comment: In a simulator, it actually works quite well if you comment out the `.offset()` transition on `SubviewTwo`. However, in `SubviewTwo`, all views have the flag `isSource = true` (by default) - not sure if this is valid or if you need one namespace per group. When transitioning the other way there is currently no movement, presumably because there is no source for the `matchedGeometryEffect`. Not sure if it can even work when going from one to many, because of the single-source rule.